# quadratic residue difference set

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $N=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes of the form $4k+1$.  Let $\mathbb{Z}_N$ be the set of integers modulo $N$ and $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ be the units in $\mathbb{Z}_N$. Let $QR$ be the quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$. If none of $p$ and $q$ is $5$, then show that $\mathbb{Z}_N=\{a-b: a, b \in QR\}$.
That is, we need to show that $\mathbb{Z}_N$ can be expressed as difference of quadratic residues.

Actually I observed that for N being product of two primes, apart from 3 and 5, Z_N can always be represented as difference of its set of quadratic residues. I tried to prove it but I failed. That's why I asked it here.

Initially I started with primes of the form 4k+1 as -1 is a quadratic residue there. However, nothing seems to work out.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: You should edit that into your question (along with perhaps some working), and then it should be re-opened.

Comment: Also posted to MO, with no notice at either site. Very rude. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171754/quadratic-residue-difference-set

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been crossposted (and answered) on MO. This is unkind to users at both sites and encourages duplication of effort. **Don't do that.**

Answer (score 1):

Given $c$, let $x=(c+1)/2$, let $y=(c-1)/2$, where all arithmetic is done modulo $N=pq$ (so 2 is invertible), then $c=x^2-y^2$, so $c$ is a difference of two quadratic residues. But you're not allowing 0 as a quadratic residue, so we need a new argument for $c=1$ (and for $c=N-1$, but that will follow from negating the representation for $c=1$). Now, half of the numbers from 1 to $p-1$ are residues. Of the numbers from 1 to 10, since 1, 4, and 9 are residues, if no two consecutive numbers are residues, then only 4 can be residues, and in that case there must be two consecutive residues among the numbers from 11 to $p-1$. So, 1 can be written as a difference of two residues modulo $p$. The same is true modulo $q$, and then the Chinese Remainder Theorem makes it work modulo $N$.